# Google Cloud API Gateway authenticate multiple service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openapi, google-cloud-api-gateway

For the APIs hosted in GCP I'm planning to authenticate consuming services (from outside gcp environment) with the help of service accounts with private keys and API gateway.

It all works fine for one service account (`service-account-1`), i.e.:

```
paths:
    /hello:
      get:
        #...
        security:
          - service_account-1: []
securityDefinitions:
    service_account-1:
      authorizationUrl: ""
      flow: "implicit"
      type: "oauth2"
      x-google-issuer: "{service-account-1}@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/{service-account-1}@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      x-google-audiences: "{project-id}"
```

However how could I describe it so any service account from the project would have access?

**EDIT:** I would like to avoid updating openapi config on API gateway each time a new service account is created and needs an access allowed.

**UPDATE:** I ended up using Identity-Aware Proxy for securing the API to only allow the authorised service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

[Authentication between services](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticate-service-account#gcloud)

> You can define multiple security definitions in your API config, but
> each definition must have a different x-google-issuer. If you have
> created separate service accounts for each calling service, you can
> create a security definition for each service account, for example:

```
securityDefinitions:
  service-1:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "service-1@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-1@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  service-2:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "service-2@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-2@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Therefore you have to create multiple security definition.

Comment: Thanks @marian.vladoi I understand I can create the definition per service account, however that is not a very flexible approach for my case. There will be service accounts added at a later stages and I would like to avoid updating the config each time that occurs.

Comment: From my understanding, reading the documentation, the service account has to be specified in the config file

Comment: maybe you know another way using gcp environment to achieve the same..maybe different approach?

Comment: Please consider that this is a beta feature and have limited support. Also, I found that some users tried to avoid this limitation by using API keys.

Comment: So, by any chance would you happen to know what is then a recommended way for external services authentication to APIs hosted in gcp? That would be different applications/services each assigned a key/secret.

Comment: At the moment, you have to include in the config files all the service accounts. Therefore you have to updated the config file each time a new service account is created.

Comment: OK, thanks. As a note I've raise a connected question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172712/application-type-users-authenticating-to-gcp)