# Application type users authenticating to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm looking for a standard Oauth2.0 approach for the service type users authenticating to APIs hosted in GCP environment with secrets. The closest I got is a [`service accounts`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) with key pairs.

However I would like to avoid updating `ESP` config each time a new `service account` is added (like in the example below).

```
 securityDefinitions:
  service-1:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "service-1@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-1@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  service-2:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "service-2@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-2@example-project-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

    #should be possible to leave the addition of service-X to the end client without needing to update this.
```

**EDIT:** I've tried using `Identity Platform` and `ESP` config won't need updating when new users are added:

```
securityDefinitions:
    auth0:
        authorizationUrl: ""
        flow: "implicit"
        type: "oauth2"
        x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/{google-project-ID}"
        x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
        x-google-audiences: "{google-project-ID}"
```

however email/password is not an option for my case and `GCP Identity Platform` doesn't seem to support users with secrets, unless I'm missing something?

It would also be good to have a possibility to add custom claims against users, which would remove a need to maintain the permissions table within the API code.

`Apigee` has all the required functionality however seems to be an expensive over-complication for my project needs.

Comment: Identity Platform allows users to [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication) to your apps and services, like multi-tenant SaaS apps, mobile/web apps, games, APIs and more. You can explore [Authentication strategies](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#strategies). To create user, you might need to explore G-Suite which is similar to Azure AD. Can you explain the question with your use cases?

Comment: I need to create users with secrets (and preferably have a possibility to add claims) rather than with emails/passwords.

Comment: You can create secret using GCP [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#create)

Comment: How will one use  a secret from `Secret Manager` with user's OAuth authentication?

Comment: It seems the feature is currently not available. I would suggest you file a issue using [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Identity-Aware Proxy`](https://cloud.google.com/iap) provides the functionality for my use-case.
When adding the service account just set the `IAP-secured Web App User` and it will have access to a secured resource. [google doc here](https://cloud.google.com/context-aware-access/docs/securing-app-engine)

[image]